# manipulate cells of a list with jquery

Tags: jquery, list-view

I am modifying the Allitems view of a list and want to select each row with a specific title and change the last cell of that row to show the thumbnail of an image with jquery.

```
var results = data.d.results;
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    $("tr.ms-vb").filter(":contains('" + results[i].Title + "')").each(function() {
        $("td.ms-vb-lastCell").append($("<img>").prop("websitelink/_t/" + results[i].Title + "_jpg.jpg"))
    });
```

it make no changes or even errors.I have tried different classes for the selector, but none of them worked. 
does someone has any idea that what is wrong?

Comment: 2007? 2010? 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2010 you can [stuff HTML in a Calculated Column](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How),

so if I read your use-case correct you need the Formula:

```
=IF( FIND("needle",[Title]) , "<img src='websitelink/_t/" & [Title] & ".jpg'/>" )
```

For testing make it output as text to see if the created HTML is correct

Then **switch the datatype to Number!!!** ét voila (that's French) it works..

Remember: FIND is Case-Sensitive, use SEARCH if you do not care about the CaSe. More SP functions at https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: I have tried the following in a new column as formula: =IF( FIND( [Title]  , "<img src='websitelink/_t/" & [Title] & "_jpg.jpg'/>" , "no Image")) but it is not supported! i assume it is not supported for images.

Comment: Its working now, Thanks @Danny . I had to choose numbers as data type returned.